# How to avoid xss atack in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

I am relatively new to web development. And just today my teacher told me to implement a method to avoid cross server scripting in my project. I have searched a lot and found about `xss_clean` but i am not sure how to use and implement it. Any guide or article related to that would be welcome. Or if you want to explain here that would save me a lot of extra hard work i will be very thankful to you. I am using `CodeIgniter` framework so please any article related to that would be good.

Comment: Have a look at Codeigniter's [Security Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/security.html)

Comment: Also check out [this](http://www.gregaker.net/2011/mar/30/what-is-xss_clean-in-codeigniter-and-why-should-i-use-it/) and [this](http://ponderwell.net/2010/08/codeigniter-xss-protection-is-good-but-not-enough-by-itself/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with XSS vulnerabilities is that you can't just apply one *fix*. These vulnerabilities can occur in every little thing you write.

XSS happens when an attacker is able to inject HTML into the page of a visitor of your website. Depending on what that code is he could send the visitor to his phishing website or steal his session.

It's not hard to imagine how you can prevent HTML injection: you just HTML-escape all user input. But in practice there can be quite a bit of this and your system is only as secure as the weakest link.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, CI's XSS is pretty good -- I have run into situations where it does remove something which I have wanted which can be a pain to debug if you're not expecting it. I've never been able to "easily" circumvent it nor have I read about any exploits (and the CI community is fairly large).

For details take a look below link which may help you
http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2011/05/codeigniter-2-0-2-cross-site-scripting-xss-fixes-and-recommendations/

Read this also https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

for removing xss attack you can do following things:

1. you need to remove unwanted tag like "`script`" from `post` and `get` value.
2. remove `meta-characters` from `post` and `get` value.

Comment: I actually don't want to remove anything. I just want want to disable it. It is a message box. What ever user enters it is displayed as it is in another box but if he enters scripts, tags etc they are disabled.

Comment: you can do one thing, when user enter some thing then you can check it for xss attack and restrict to user to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

a very short and simple answer use following line of code where you are submitting your details that mince in your controller file.

```
$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
```

here data may your single value or array in case you have multiple records.

one more addon to your query.use following to protect from sql injection

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM subscribers_tbl WHERE user_name = '.
$this->db->escape($email);
$this->db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this functionality for protection against XSS attacks:

```
public static function protectArrayAgainstXSS(&$arr) {
    $changed = false;
    foreach ($arr as $index => $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            $changed = $changed || Common::protectArrayAgainstXSS($arr[$index]);
        } else if ($a !== null) {
            $changed = $changed || ($arr[$index] === strip_tags($a));
            $arr[$index] = strip_tags($a);
        }
    }
    return !$changed;
}
```